# Want to redirect domain to blog in subfolder until full site launches

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

I am in the process of launching a full website that will be ready in about 6-9 months but I have a self-hosted Wordpress blog created in the meantime to start building a userbase and SEO.  So since there will eventually be more to my site than a blog, my blog is located in a subfolder in my root domain (www.website.com/blog).  I would like for my root domain (www.website.com) to automatically send users to my blog (www.website.com/blog).  Once the full site is ready, I then want my users to enter my domain and be sent to the regular site and not the blog.

Through my searching, it seems like I will either have to set up a 301 or 302 redirect, which I understand how to do.  The question is which one to use to prevent negative SEO once the full site launches.  I have a feeling I should use a 302 redirect since it is a temporary redirect, but from what I have been reading, it seems like this may hurt my SEO on the popular search engines.

Your help would be greatly appreciated and I can provide more details if needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to use **external redirect** and handle this via **internal redirect** only. That way your URL never changes and search engines will not index wrong URL. In your .htaccess put these rules for this purpose:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/+blog [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog/$1 [L,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /blog [R=302]
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: My question is whether or not a 302 redirect is the best option in terms of SEO.  Are you saying that it is or should a internal redirect like anubhava mentioned be better?